# Pass parameter from a URL to a XSL stylesheet

Tags: url, xslt

I just spent the past couple of days digging into the messages looking for a way to pass a parameter from an URL to a XSL stylesheet.

for example, I have a **current url** like:

```
http://localhost/blocableau/data/base_bloc/blocableau3x.xml?95.2
```

and I want to just select the value after the ? like the `95.2` in this example, and put it in the variable `var_massif`.

I tried the following code with javascript for test the value substring(1) but with xsl it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<!-- recherche des cotations par Massif selon une variable -->

<xsl:key name="byMassif" match="bloc" use="Massif" />

<xsl:template match="BLOCS"> 

<script>var requete = location.search.substring(1); 
mavariable=requete;alert(mavariable);x=mavariable</script>


<xsl:variable name="var_massif"><xsl:value-of select="95.2" /></xsl:variable> 
<span>Ma variable xsl est : <xsl:value-of select="$var_massif"/></span>


   <div style="position:relative; top:0px;left:10px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica, sans-serif'; font-size:12px;z-index:1;">

      <!-- genere un id pour chaque valeur de cotation et mise en forme -->

     <xsl:for-each select="bloc[generate-id() = generate-id(key('byMassif', $var_massif)[1])]" >
             <xsl:sort select="Massif" />
```

Comment: What language are you using to process your XSLT - PHP, JS etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are loading a XML which uses a XSL processing instruction to transform the file:

```
 <?xml-stylesheet ... ?>
```

You would need to read the URL and extract the query string. Unfortunately it is not automatically mapped. The only way to do that would be using `document-uri(/)` but it's XSLT 2.0 and not supported in browsers.

In XSLT 1.0 you would have to direct your HTTP request not to the XML file you want to process, but to a script which will load your XML and XSLT using the `XSLTProcessor`. Then you could pass the query-string as a parameter to the processor:

```
var var_massif = location.search.substring(1); // gets the string and removes the `?`
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();  // starts the XSL processor
processor.setParameter(null, "var_massif", var_massif);  // sets parameter
... // load XSL, XML and transformToDocument
```

Inside your XSLT stylesheet you should have a global parameter variable:

```
<xsl:param name="var_massif" />
```

Which you will then be able to read with `$var_massif`.

**UPDATE** Here is a step-by-step example using JQuery:

I'm using this reduced stylesheet, just to show you how to get the parameter. It's in a file I called `stylesheet.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="var_massif" />

    <xsl:template match="BLOCS">
        <span>Ma variable xsl est : <xsl:value-of select="$var_massif" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this input (`blocableau3x.xml`) in the same directory:

```
<BLOCS>
    <bloc>
        <Massif></Massif>
    </bloc>
</BLOCS>
```

Now create this HTML file (blocableau3x.html) also in the same directory:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var var_massif = location.search.substring(1); // gets the string and removes the `?`
        var body = $("body")[0]; // gets the body element where the result will be inserted

        if (var_massif) {
            var processor = new XSLTProcessor();  // starts the XSL processor
            processor.setParameter(null, "var_massif", var_massif);

            var source;

            var xslReq = $.get("stylesheet.xsl", function (data) { // loads the stylesheet
                processor.importStylesheet(data);
            });
            var xmlReq = $.get("blocableau3x.xml", function (data) { // loads the xml
                source = data;
            });

            $.when(xslReq, xmlReq).done(function () { // waits both to load
                var result = processor.transformToDocument(source);  // transforms document
                body.appendChild(result.documentElement); // adds result as child of body element
            });

        } else {
            body.html("<h1>Missing query string</h1>"); // in case there is no query string
        }
    });
</script>

<html>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Instead of calling your XML file in the URL, call the HTML file. When it loads, it will load the XSL file and the XML file, and use the XSL processor to process the file. It will be able to read the query parameter and pass it as a XSL global parameter, which you can read in your XSLT file.

Comment: I try this but it didn'nt work :-(
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="var_massif" /> 
<xsl:key name="byMassif" match="bloc" use="Massif" />
<xsl:template match="BLOCS"> 
<xsl:variable name="var_massif"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(document-uri(/), '?')" /></xsl:variable> 
<span>Ma variable xsl est : <xsl:value-of select="$var_massif"/></span>

Comment: If you are loading the XML file using a Web browser, it probably won't work because of no XSLT 2.0 support, so you should try the JavaScript solution. If you are loading the file using some other application, you also have to check if the parser you are using supports XSLT 2.0, since the `document-uri()` function won't work if it does not.

Comment: Yes I use my browser for looading xml file.I'm a dummies in code and  I don't see how doing.

Comment: The javascript solution with this code don't work.

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="byMassif" match="bloc" use="Massif" />
<xsl:template match="BLOCS"> 

<script>
var_massif = location.search.substring(1); 
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();  
processor.setParameter(null, "var_massif", var_massif); 
alert(var_massif); 
</script>
<xsl:variable name="var_massif"><xsl:value-of select="$var_massif" /></xsl:variable>

Comment: It will work if you place it inside an HTML file, call the HTML file which will load the XSL + XSLT via Ajax. I will show you an example.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you. thank you very much.
Now, I'll have to understand how use this code in my xml file.
I dive in.

Comment: Hi! I spend the night to try use use your way but I'din't find :-(
here my test_original without a good var_massif
http://blocableau.com/a_test_original/livesearch.html
here your solution but without html page résult but var_massif is good :-((
http://blocableau.com/a_test/livesearch.html

Comment: I don't know what livesearch is nor anything about PHP. This does not seem in any way related to your question.

Comment: hi "php  livesearch"  just for call the xml files. I present you the two options in the context for try to understand why your code not produce result  html result. I show you the files and I hope you can help me. Now with your code we have the value of var_massif it's wonderfull but no extraction xml values with the xsl file on the hmtl and I don't understand it's curious. the two  xls's files  have the same structure.

Thank from France

Comment: Obtain the variable is interresting but if I can't use in the muenchian grouping I'm always with the same pb
<xsl:for-each select="bloc[generate-id() = generate-id(key('byMassif', $var_massif)[1])]" >

Comment: Perhaps you could post a new question including all that you have so far, and posting the full XSL, the input you have and the expected result.

Comment: hi, I find the error thta's because your stylesheet.xsl contain an error " <xsl:key name="byMassif" match="bloc" use="Massif" />" before template was missing. I didn't  saw the mistake. may be you could change your answer by:<?xml version="1.0" ?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" /><xsl:param name="var_massif" /><xsl:key name="byMassif" match="bloc" use="Massif" /><xsl:template match="BLOCS"> <span>My variable xsl "$var_massif"  is : <xsl:value-of select="$var_massif" /></span>

thank a lot, I'm very glad :-))